# Extra white space at the bottom of my website

Tags: html, css

I'm making a section with a height of 100vh, but I don't know why I'm getting extra white space or more than 100vh height due to which its adding scroll bar and white space.

Here is my HTML code :

```css
#second {
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 10vw;
  padding-top: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.elem {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3.5vw 3vw;
  border-top: 1px solid #888;
}

.elem h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 7.6vw;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.elemlast {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="second">
  <div class="elem">
    <h1>The Plug</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    <h1>ixperience</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    <h1>hudu</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you guys please take a look and tell me what am I doing wrong.

Excuse my English.

Comment: body has a default margin, reset body to margin:0 and it will  avoid any element of 100vh's height to start to be print at average 1em from top of the browser's view but from 0  ... Aside , horizontal scrolling on html or body are also in the way. here is an old but reliable post : https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/

Answer (score 1):

I always get used to this when starting any HTML/CSS projects.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Edit:

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none; /* webkit based */
   }
   scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}

#second {
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 10vw;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.elem {
  width: 100%;
  /*padding: 3.5vw 3vw;*/
  border-top: 1px solid #888;
}

.elem h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 7.6vw;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.elemlast {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="second">
  <div class="elem">
    <h1>The Plug</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    <h1>ixperience</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="elem">
    <h1>hudu</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this what u want?

Also, if u wanna hide the scrollbar, but still want it to be scrollable, add:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none; /* webkit based */
}
scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
```

Comment: Its already 0 and box sizing to border-box  at the start of my project. I dont what is caushing extra vh and whitespace

Comment: @sareb ur padding in `.elem` causes the whitespace. check my edit on my answer

Comment: yes after removing the padding white space was gone but i want to give some padding like i did which was casuing the white space but is there any way that i can give padding to my divs without getting the white space? or do i have to give padding and reduce the height?

Comment: @sareb U could maintain the padding, but the page will be scrollable

Comment: @sareb Would you consider giving a green check mark if you were helped by my answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reset all the margin and padding and also set `box-sizing: border-box` so that border and padding are included to the total height of the containers. And finally, for the `#second` id set a responsive `padding-top` value so that it doesn't force the content to overflow.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#second {
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 10vw;
    /* padding-top: 200px; */
    /* padding-top: 5vh; */
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.elem {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3.5vw 3vw;
    border-top: 1px solid #888;
}

.elem h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 7.6vw;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.elemlast {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="second">
    <div class="elem">
      <h1>The Plug</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
      <h1>ixperience</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
      <h1>hudu</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing simple view port height to the div of interest gives the height of 100vh to the specific inner div but in that we do need to remove the margin and padding for the body element if any present.

It's always a good idea to define this early in the root stylesheet to override.

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}
```

also you can use similar thing for overriding overall font's and similar inputs by using

```
html, body {
}
```